# Confused about basic localization not actually programing

Tags: java, android

I am trying to fallow a tutorial and its about localization .I am pretty new to emulators and  I couldnt find Language menu under settings.I have tried a few different emulator .The other  thing is that I am wondering what kind of differences between emulators .Which one is the best for an absolute beginner

Answer (score 0):

**Real Testing Device:**

> Testing on real device allows you to run your mobile applications and
>   checks its functionality. Real device testing assures you that your
>   application will work smoothly in customer handsets.

**Emulators:**

> Emulator is a software program that allows your mobile to imitate the
>   features of another computer or mobile software you want them to
>   imitate by installing them to your computer or Mobile.

Considering the significant role the mobile applications is playing nowadays play now days in our day to day life, testing of these applications are going to evolve and thus they require a lot of testing to make them work as required.Testing in both the emulator as well as the real world devices is necessary to maintain strong standards and quality assurance.

Best practices would indicate that actual development should use emulators (and a few reference real handsets) in order to speed up the debugging of the application during the coding phase, while sanity, smoke testing, performance, interoperability and network feasibility and regression testing should be done on real handsets.

It is also an emerging practice to ensure that the developers use the emulator for fast execution during the development phase whereas then the testing team should test with the real device during the testing phase in order to ensure overall quality assurance goals and targets.To save on cost, they can consider using Virtual Mobile Testing tools. These services offer developer to test their application on wide variety of handsets using different mobile networks geographically located throughout the world (useful for applications using GPS). Such services are offered on hourly basis and are very cost effective compared to buying new phones.